# To have 2 DIVs overlapping and other DIVs below

Tags: php, html, css

I've got 2 DIVs overlap one another. Now how do I avoid any new  overlapping? Everything seems to be overlapping one another.

All I want is only `<DIV class = "containerA">` and `<DIV class = "containerB">` to overlap and any new DIV to show below these above DIVs.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/nLsBZ/9/)

Comment: wouldn't you just set the position of the divs below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give position relative to A and C with B having position absolute

**CSS**

```
.containerC{

    position:relative
}
.subContainerA{
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.subContainerB{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzML9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper `div`. Try this code

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/nLsBZ/11/)**

```
    <div class="topCnt">
        <img class = "subContainerB" src="http://s30.postimg.org/mf5cny17l/top_Img.png" />

        <svg class="subContainerA" preserveAspectRatio= "xMinYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 200 240" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <g>
            <rect stroke-opacity="0" id="svg_3" height="240" width="200" y="2.5" x="2.5" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
            <rect id="svg_4" height="84" width="408" y="430" x="769" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
            </g>
         </svg>
    </div>

    .topCnt{
       position: relative;
       height: 480px;
    }
```